# cannot borrow `req` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust

I didn't understand why `req` has been borrowed mutably. There is no `&mut` before `req`
If I comment `let group_email = body.email.as_str()`,, the error is gone. Why?

```
pub async fn post(mut req: Request<State>) -> tide::Result {
    let state = req.state().clone();
    let db = &state.db;
    let body: RequestBody = req.body_json().await?;
    let group_email = body.email.as_str();
    let group_name = body.name.as_str();
    let group_password = body.passwd.as_str();

    let transaction = db.transaction(move |conn| {
        //Omit the unrelated code
     });
```

The error is:

Does req.body_json() mutable borrow req?

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `req` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   --> src/api/account/register.rs:64:29
    |
45  |       let state = req.state().clone();
    |                   ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
64  |       let body: RequestBody = req.body_json().await?;
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
69  |       let transaction = db.transaction(move |conn| {
    |  _______________________-
70  | |  
71  | |         let already_exists = sql::select(sql::exists(
72  | |             authors::table.filter(authors::email.eq(body.email.as_str())),
...   |
117 | |         Ok(utils::response::json(&response))
118 | |     });
    | |______- immutable borrow later used here
```

I tried delete

```
  let group_email = body.email.as_str();
    let group_name = body.name.as_str();
```

And everything works fine.

Comment: The `mut` is written in the parameter definition, `mut req`. And yes, if you check [the docs](https://docs.rs/tide/latest/tide/struct.Request.html#method.body_json), you'll see they say that `body_json()` mutably borrows.

Comment: Could you do `body_json()` first and then get `state` and `db` later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a http request there is 2 steps:

1. Send the data

   ```
   let mut req = reqwest.get("soemthing").set_header("...")
   ```
2. Receive the data

   ```
   req.body_json()
   ```

The reason `req` needs to be mutable is because `body_json` consumes the buffer that contains the response inside the req object.

This means that as soon as you call `req.body_json()` the data is no longer in the request object, which inlines with Rust goals to of being memory efficient.
This is even more clear when you use methods such as `req.body()` which simply "moves" the data with 0 copying and 0 allocations.

This is why you can no longer call `req.body_json()` again and why the `req` needs to be mutable

Comment: Thanks for your replying. But why consume a variable, it is necessary to declare this variable into `mut`?